# REST API Node port in an enterprise application

Tags: node.js, rest, port, firewall

I have an `Angular` application that communicates with a `Node / Express` `REST API`.

This `API` runs on port `82`.

Our company sells licences to this application to enterprises and larger organisations such as `Banks`, `Television`, `Construction` ect.

Many of these organisations have a tight security network in place that sometimes disallow the port our `API` is running on which means that they are unable to access the content until their `IT` department has opened this port.

In some cases the organisation have a policy that they will not open the specific port which results in a lost sale which is very bad!

The problem is im unable to change ports because it is different for each of the organisation which ports are open and which are closed.

So my question is how do i get around this? am i doomed to loose clients because of their security system or is there a work around? i am thinking that im not the only one with this issue...

Comment: why you are not using port 80?

Comment: @Hiren Apache runs on port 80

Comment: @Hiren also if i changed the apache port they wouldnt be able to connect to my site would they??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were writing this, i'd have the port in a config file along with all your other application-wide definitions (credentials/api keys etc).  Your clients should have people on staff with the know-how to set up some proxy routing for whatever port your node app is running on, and your API should refer to the port via call to the config file (I'm pretty sure most of the node/express docs do this by design).

By doing this, it doesn't matter to your API which port it's running on, and it's down to the client to define and support a port that they allow on their network.

**EDIT:** just seen your comment in another answer that you're hosting the API and they're connecting to it.  In that case, it *would* be easier (and better industry practice) to expose your API on port 80.  If you've already got Apache running on 80, then you need to proxy your API within your own infrastructure from the port it's running on to an endpoint on the same port (in the same way that you can have multiple sites running against port 80 as they have different URLs)

Something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  ServerName api.somehost.com
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:82/ Keepalive=On
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:82/
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ....
</VirtualHost>
```

So therefore when your client points a REST call at your `api.somehost.com`, it enters your infrastructure through port 80, and is routed to your API running on port 82.  Make sure you have enabled the proxy module (`a2enmod proxy`)

Comment: this might work sadly the costumers does not have the know how since many of their secruity features are managed in a foreign country and the hassle for making this change is not something they want.

Comment: See above, this might be more what you are looking for :)

Comment: with the proxy am i able to even start my server if port 80 is already being used by apache

Comment: Well you wouldn't be starting your API server on port 80, you'd be starting it on 82, then your Apache config would be doing the internal routing, so there would be no port clash

Comment: just to get things straight i would have to create a virtualhost and then enable it using a2ensite with the above settings you posted?

Comment: Yes that's correct.  That is potentially one way of doing it, but you may need to define a Document Root in those settings as well (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html)

Comment: when i try this i get an apache error saying ProxyPass is an invalid command

Comment: Try `a2enmod proxy`.  You may need others, but that should get you going.  Digital ocean has a good article about it: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88457/discussion-between-marc-rasmussen-and-stephen-wright).

Answer (score 1):

In case of using Web Server at the servers of your clients, they're just need to add proxy to your backend, running on any free port

like this for nginx

```
    location ^~ /nodeapp/ {
        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:82/;
    }
```

So, all the urls of client `http://website.org/nodeapp/anything`
goes to your nodejs instance `/anything`. Your app reachable via opened 80 port

If it's not allowed to use and change config of existing web server, then the only one option to set up nodejs listen port with args `--port 4000`
and explicit opening that port to external network

Comment: my clients are not self hosting our company hosts the server for them they only need to connect to our port.

Comment: It's not important where company hosting are. Someone need to add Proxy to nodejs app (good way), or open port for external network (not secure way). Port needs to be set up via config file or args